# Data loading speed issue in Calendar Event Module

Tags: c#, winforms, lazy-loading, amazon-lightsail

Is there a way to fix this loading speed issue?, perhaps by ignoring the section that doesn't contain pending orders in a certain date? It takes around 10 seconds to finish loading.

[image: The loading progress is shown here:]

[image: Completed loading progress shown here]

Here is my code:

```
query = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders_list` WHERE `Ordered_Date` = '{0}' AND `Status` = 'For Delivery'", Program.stcYear + "-" + Program.stcMonth + "-" + lblDay.Text);
            Program.ExecuteCommand(query);
            if (Program.reader.Read())
            {
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(Program.reader.GetString(0));
                if(count >= 1)
                {
                    lblPendings.Text = "Pending: " + count;
                }
            }
            Program.CloseConnections();
```

I've just tried turning off the display of the 0 pending values, but it didn't help.

Comment: Is this code running for each tile? Also welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: It looks like this is being run for each day. Each round trip to the database involves time. Figure out your start and end dates and use a single query.

Comment: @Mohammed Thank you for your warm welcome :).
Yes, it is. The code runs in User Control Form (Event "Load"), my query runs in each and every tile and the tile is looped based on the month's date to accurately design the calendar.
As Jonathan indicated, I need to figure out how to limit the query's execution to a specific date.

Comment: @Diaz no problem and as Jonathan said the reason why I asked is because that is very inefficient. Put everything in one query, and fill your calendar with results from that query. Your query will need a date column that associates results with the days.